# more VARBINARY columns in result set fo SQL Server R sript

Tags: r, sql-server

In my R script for MS SQL Server I try to return one column VARBINARY() and one VARCHAR(). However, server  allow only one column when VARBINARY is returned:

```
There can be only one column in the result set when using the 'varbinary' data type.
```

Example code:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language =N'R',
    @script=N'R,
    ff = tempfile();
    png(filename=ff, width=800, height=800);
    plot(...);
    dev.off();
    f1 = file(ff,"rb");
    d1 = readBin(f1, what=raw(), n=1e6);
    dd = data.frame(d1, c("plot1");
    colnames(dd) = c("plot", "title");
    OutputDataSet = dd;',
    @input_data_1 =N'SELECT * FROM table_name'
    WITH RESULT SETS ((plot varbinary(max)), (dsc varchar(20));
```

How to return additional columns with VARBINARY column?

Comment: So us your actual code here.

Comment: Example code:
.....
        d1 = readBin(f1, what=raw(), n=1e6);
 dd = data.frame(d1, c("histogram"));
 
 OutputDataSet = dd;',
 @input_data_1 =N'SELECT * FROM ...'
 WITH RESULT SETS ((plot varbinary(max)), (dsc varchar(20));

Comment: Please post the R script and what line the error is happening on.